# WPF trigger based on property a cell is bound too

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, triggers

So I would like to change the background color of any dataGridCell.

The DateGrid.ItemsSource is bound to a class something like this.

```
public class OldData
{
   public Cell Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
   public object Value  { get; set; }
   public Boolean DoesMatch { get; set; }    
}
```

I have been trying to set up a cell template with a trigger on DoesMatch, but wpf cannot seem to find it.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgNew" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DoesMatch, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type lib:Cell}}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF35656" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </DataGrid.CellStyle>
 </DataGrid>
```

I have tried several variations of the template, but they spit out Data errors into my output window, and of coerce, my cell backgrounds don't change. :)

WPF Output Error:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='CsvDataCompareTool.Lib.Cell', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DoesMatch; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

tried it without relativeSource

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DoesMatch}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF35656" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Error:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DoesMatch' property not found on 'object' ''NewData' (HashCode=53750044)'. BindingExpression:Path=DoesMatch; DataItem='NewData' (HashCode=53750044); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: Doesn't it work without the RelativeSource?

Comment: That is what I started with, and got a very similar wpf data error in out put. I can try it again, and update my question if you think it would help.

Comment: So your itemssource is a collection of `NewItem` objects which have a property of type `Cell` called Name, right?

Comment: correct...I need to display cell.value, and change background color based on cell.DoesMatch

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Hope it makes sense. (In you binding error message it looks like the class is called NewData, but in the provided code it's called OldData).

Comment: yeah, this is a tool to compare data between csv files (fun little side project)  I generate proxy classes called oldData and NewData, and the idea is to compare the sets of data and markup the data grid all pretty like, to make it simpler to visualize where mismatches are.  See my comment on your answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The datacontext of each cell in the `DataGrid` will be set to the `OldData` object it represents, so you should be able to bind directly to it without using a `RelativeSource` binding.

But since `DoesMatch` is not a property on `OldData` but on `Cell`, you have to bind to `Name.DoesMatch` instead, like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgNew" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name.DoesMatch}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF35656" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: my OldData class actually has many properties of type Cell, both the class and it's properties are dynamically generated. So I won't know at design time what the property names are.

Comment: I see the problem, but don't see a nice way to solve it. How are you planning on setting the value in the cell? Won't that result in the same issue?

Comment: once I get the initial binding going, then I will wire in change notification. Trying to avoid doing any of the compare logic in the UI. I'm thinking I can make this work if do some code behind work and define the columns/triggers dynamically ... thanks for looking into it tho :)